# jQuery Tools Tabs Nested Control?

Tags: jquery, tabs, jquery-tools

Can anyone help out with this, it would be a big help?

A simple tab set up like below (it will be vertical though...)

http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/index.htm

However, is it possible to have control over the tabs from within the tab content?

So you have 3 buttons that load 3 tab areas.

Then within each tab area are those 3 buttons again that do the exact same as the main buttons and also have an active style...

Think of it like a tv, the remote control controls the channels but also the buttons on the tv, also controls them...

Can it be done?

Thanks so much for any help :)

Comment: jQuery Tools is a stagnant project in badly need of a rewrite and looking for a new developer.  IMHO, stay away from it and find a more solid plugin.  What's being discussed in [this article about jQuery Tools](http://marcgrabanski.com/articles/jquery-tools-vs-jquery-ui) still holds true today, even if you don't prefer to use jQuery UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery UI tabs for that:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

You can play around with options and get thing that you need. You can have full control over the over the tabs.

Comment: That doesn't answer his question... he's asking about jQuery Tools, not jQuery UI.

Comment: jQuery Tools was just an example i found for tabs, all i need is a vertical tab structure really doesn't have to be that...

Comment: I tried to add the tab navigation again within the tab content and it doesn't work, obviously not styled but it doesn't work like the main nav... :(